# Function level static variable NOT static for lazy book keeping

Tags: c++, static

I want to use a function level variable for book keeping since I do not want to pollute my code with a ton of member variables like this:

```
class A
{
void funcA() {
    // ...
    static int oldValue = -1;
    if (oldValue != newValue) {
        loadNewData();
        oldValue = newValue;
    }
}
};
```

But I need the variable `oldValue` to be **not static** to have a unique check for each instance of this class. Is there a way to use this lazy instantiation of a book-keeping variable but on a per-instance level?

Comment: Very short answer: No, it is not possible. If you want per-instance data, use instance variables. There is no other way.

Comment: I've never heard of anybody being worried about name pollution within a class. You wouldn't be implementing the most massive [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) of all time, would you?

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Well, there are other ways, but the cure is worse than the disease.  (You could keep them in a map indexed by the `this` pointer, for example.)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: no, actually the class is quite simple - there would be only 3-4 of such oldValues. But personally I think that the code would be more readable and prevent tinkering with those variables in other places. What a pity that it is not possible

Comment: @PhilLab Data *belongs* to the object, not the method.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer and that's good. Basically I am looking for a little bit of syntactic sugar in a way which (I believe) would not violate OOP principles. After all, the above is possible for a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to use a non-static variable in a function scope and use it to track previous values assigned in previous invocations. A regular variable will just be assigned `-1`, as in your example, and will sequentially hold the values of the assignments that follow (as you seem aware).

Your case is precisely the case when to use instance variables, since you need private mutable state associated to a certain method's content. You might even say it is the case for an instance variable by an OO definition/approach.

It is also easy to provide a lazy initializer for an instance variable in a getter, encapsulating that same initialization logic for every method that uses it.

While there might be other methods to work around the problem, they don't seem like the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try but probably the following would work.

Instead of a single Variable , use a static array/List with an other variable which counts the instance number.